# Birthday reminders in my phone start 12 hours prior for birthdays stored in Gmail contacts

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean, notifications, calendar, htc-one-x

I store birthdays in my Gmail contacts. I have HTC One X with Android 4.2.2 and Sense 5. I have synced my calendars with Gmail contacts and all the birthdays are visible in my calendar app on Android. But the reminder for each of the birthday is set to 12 hours prior.

[image]

I don't want to reminded of someone's birthday 12 hours before! Is there any way to customize this time? Or remove it completely for all the birthday reminders coming from Gmail contacts?

Comment: I guess your timezone is utc-12?

Comment: @davidbaumann: I stay in India so my time zone would be set to UTC +05:30. How can I check it?

Answer (score -1):

First, go to your phone Settings > Date and Time and check if your time zone is correct.

Second, change the time zone of your Google account by following [this guide](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en).

Good luck!

Comment: My settings are set to "Use network provided time" and "Use network provided time zone". This sets my time zone to GMT +05:30 India Standard Time.

Comment: How about your Google account?

Comment: Checked my calendar settings and it shows India Standard Time in time zone. Same goes for my Google account. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you're using the default calendar app that comes with HTC Sense. Try this: go to settings of that app and set default reminder time to something shorter. If that doesn't work, try to download the google calendar app from Play Store and use it instead of HTC one.

Comment: I went to settings of the app but there is no setting for default reminder. And even if I download the Calendar app from Play store the stock calendar app would still sync and it would give me reminders before 12 hours.